# Why does searching a PostgreSQL index for recently-deleted value take so long?

Tags: postgresql

Trying to test that a delete query worked as expected, I want to run a simple select query, but the query just hangs and never completes. Looking at `pg_stat_activity` it looks like the query is running with the `wait_event` changing between `DataFileRead` and other states (including `NULL`, and surprisingly, `WalWrite`).

The explained query:

```sql
explain select *
from public.some_table
where foreign_id = 99
limit 1
```

Shows the expected query plan:

```
Limit  (cost=0.58..4.51 rows=1 width=45)
  ->  Index Scan using idx_unique_cols on "some_table"  (cost=0.58..32.04 rows=8 width=45)
        Index Cond: (foreign_id = 99)
```

`idx_unique_cols` has this DDL:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_unique_cols ON public."some_table" USING btree (foreign_id DESC, col1, col2 DESC, foreign_id_2);
```

The table is fairly large - around 380GB, and I expect around 50 million rows per `foreign_id`. I was expecting a fairly quick index scan to determine that there are no rows with a `foreign_id` of 99. But that is clearly not happening and I don't know why the query would take so long.

Questions:

1. Why would this query ever need to wait on a `WalWrite` event (I'm assuming that this means the select query, for some reason, requires writing to the Write-Ahead Log)
2. Looking at the index, why would it take so long to determine that a value in the index doesn't exist?
3. Running the same query on a `foreign_key` value that I know is much higher than exists in `some_table` returns instantly. Why would running the query on a value that is lower than existing values in the table take so long to return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only scenario that comes to my mind is that there were lots of rows with `foreign_id = 99` deleted recently. In PostgreSQL, `DELETE` doesn't remove rows from the table (and the index!) immediately, but marks them as invisible. Later, autovacuum will actually remove the deleted entries. If autovacuum hasn't processed the table yet, the following will happen:

- all the deleted entries are still in the index, and PostgreSQL has to fetch the table rows to determine that they are deleted, which can take a long time
- if the table rows are truly dead (nobody can see them any more), PostgreSQL will "kill the index entries" (free the space in the table and mark the entries in table and index as dead), so that subsequent queries can save themselves the effort

There is some more information in [this article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/killed-index-tuples/).

If my theory is correct, running the same query a second time should be much faster, and `VACUUM` would speed it up even more.

Comment: Thank you for the answer - that is probably it. There is a vaccum query running `autovacuum: VACUUM public.some_table`. But it seems to have been running for a very long time. How can I tell, looking at `pg_stat_activity` whether a query that looks like it's active is just hanging? (does this happen with PostgreSQL 15?)

Comment: That is normal, particularly if `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay` is set too high.

Comment: @ZachSmith barring bugs, queries don't "just hang".  That the wait_event is changing (and more importantly the state_change is changing) is evidence that *something* is happening, although I guess in theory you could have an infinite loop which spans over a status update.